# Как удалить комментарии из DOM дерева?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь удалить комментарии из контейнера, так как потом работаю с потомками этого контейнера используя firstChild в цикле.
Удаляю ненужных потомков таким образом, но комментарии остаются

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.wrapperItemsContainer.childNodes.length; i++) {    
    if (this.wrapperItemsContainer.childNodes[i].nodeName === "#text" ||
        this.wrapperItemsContainer.childNodes[i].nodeName === "#comment") {
            this.wrapperItemsContainer.childNodes[i].remove()
    }
}
```

Комментарии в html

```
<!-- some comment -->
```

Хочу отдельно обратить внимание, что потомки с `nodeName === "#text"` удаляются. А вот с `nodeName === "#comment"` нет, хотя внутрь условия проходят.

Comment: Нельзя менять массив, по которому проходитесь циклом. Когда вы удаляете текст, вы смещаете позиции следующих элементов на 1 влево и из-за `i++` вы дитятку с комментарием просто пропускаете в цикле. Сделайте хотя бы `i--` после удаления.

Comment: Спасибо! Бесит когда так тупишь)